# Find the elements in the last row of a matrix given the elements of the first row without using a full loop

Tags: c, algorithm, python-3.x

I have been given the elements of the first row of a matrix and the total number of rows of the matrix

```
a[i][j] =a[i-1][j] ^ a[i-1][j+1] // ^ is XOR operation
a[i][-1] = a[i-1][-1] ^ a[i-1][0] // elements in the last column
```

How can I find the elements of the last row of the matrix without applying a full loop?

I tried to find a pattern and found that after some rows, elements of the rows thereafter, are obtained from shifting some elements of some previous row

Comment: Please mention the matrix you are given, it may help us finding a solution!

Comment: take a matrix of 5 columns and 10 rows ...The elements of the first matrix are 1 2 3 4 5 ...the elements of 5th row can be obtained by right-shifting elements of 2 row . Similiarly for the elements of the 6 row and so on